# How to repair a Shark nv352 vacuum cleaner motor gasket?

Tags: repair, vacuum

Here is a Shark nv352 vacuum cleaner motor with a broken gasket:

[image: broken gasket]

A closeup:

[image: closeup of gasket]

It seems to be 3 3/4" in diameter.  I'm not sure of the material.  It is not currently pliable.

The motor works perfectly well, but the vacuum cleaner started making a huge whining noise.  I think this gasket probably dampens vibration?

Anyway, is it possible to buy a replacement gasket? Is it standard?  What is it made of?

It seems to be somewhat stuck on.  I imagine I can pry the rest of it off with a screwdriver, but I don't know if I can get a replacement.

I can get a replacement motor on ebay.  Do I have to?  The motor itself works perfectly well.

**EDIT**: Is this a gasket, or an o-ring, or something else?  It seems to have some depth and shape to it, and I'm noticing youtube videos about cork gaskets seem to indicate they are flat.

Comment: The material looks like cork.  Not sure where to buy one, but auto parts store should have cork sheets to make one.

Comment: Oh, thanks. How does someone make one? .. Oh, I'll look on youtube.

Comment: Do you think it's a standard size? I measured 3 3/4", which seems odd. (I'm wondering if I can buy a pre-made one.)

Comment: Also, should I prefer cork, or cork-rubber?

Comment: It is not made from cork, it is custom made to fit the grove

Comment: Thanks. Custom made from what material? And, do I need to use that, or could I use cork?

Comment: I do not know the material, but you could use plumber putty and form it to fill the notch

Comment: It looks like the other half of that piece is still stuck inside the housing...

Comment: To whoever closed this: it wasn't a product or service recommendation question. It was a question about how to repair something. Fortunately, I got some good comments that led me to a good solution (scrape the gasket away, deposit silicon, which is heat resistant), which I then posted. The question and solution will not become obsolete quickly, it will work with many things in the future that have a gasket. I just happened to mention the brand.

Answer (score 3):

After scraping the old gasket away with a razor, I ended up using 100% silicone 2 to form a new gasket by depositing the silicone in a layer where the old gasket was.  It did not have to be precise, just absorb vibration.

I also put the silicone on two other plastic pieces that looked to be holding foam wedges to dampen vibration.  One of those pieces was missing.

[image: silicone]

Thanks to the comments who suggested I make a new one.